# rmarkdown not running chunks in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, r-markdown

Im trying to migrate to vscode, since I can do more things with it than rstudio. When I try to use my saved Rmd, vscode doesn't recognize that its working with chunks despite is configured in rmarkdown. When they open, they look like this:
[image]

But when I open it from a blank HTML template, they work like they have to do:
[image]

any posible fin I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? What do you mean by "vscode doesn't recognize that its working with chunks"? The chunks don't run when knit? Did you follow the [instructions about setting file associations](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/R-Markdown#file-association)?

Answer (score 14):

I hope you resolved this by now, but just in case - I too had been happily using *.Rmd with VS Code, but not for a while, and the chunks were no longer recognised as R - or chunks.

I had been using [r-lsp](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-r-lsp), which once flagged as deprecated, so I just got rid of it, in a gung-ho cull...

Now moving to [vscode-R](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R), I found I had to change the `files.associations` in VSCode's `settings.json` (Ctrl+Shift+P > Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)) from the previous value:

```json
  "files.associations": {
    "*.rmd": "markdown"
  },
```

to

```json
  "files.associations": {
    "*.Rmd": "rmd"
  }
```

Maybe it was always wrong!  Details in the vscode-R wiki, here, https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/R-Markdown.

Comment: Thank you, this sorted out the issue for me +1

Answer (score 3):

At the files associations, I found:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.rmd": "markdown",
    "*.Rmd": "rmarkdown"
},
```

And, following the recomendations, changed to:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.rmd": "rmarkdown",
    "*.Rmd": "rmd"
},
```